# Unable to print all the result within a sub procedure populated by a function

Tags: excel, vba, function, web-scraping

I've written a script in vba to print all the result within the sub procedure `PrintResult()` populated by `getPOST()` function. My current attempt is printing only the last result of the parsed content. I know it might be possible to store the result in a dictionary in order to print all them at once but can't get the idea of that particular usage.

> ***It is important to keep the existing design intact.***

Current attempt:

```
Function getPOST() As String
    Const link$ = "https://admintool.noah-connect.com/widget/attendees"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object, oName As Object, oCom As Object

    With Http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        For Each elem In Html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
            Set oName = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
            Set oCom = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(1)
            getPOST = oName.innerText & "-" & oCom.innerText
        Next elem
    End With
End Function

Sub PrintResult()
    Debug.Print getPOST()
End Sub
```

***How can I print all the result within `PrintResult()` populated by `getPOST()` function?***

Comment: Shouldn’t it be more like ... getPOST = getPOST & oName.innerText & etc.? You’ll probably want a line break in there as well or something too. There’s no reason why you couldn’t just write out to debug within getPOST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by *preserve design* so giving string return and dict 
 (as object) return methods

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PrintResult()
    Dim dict As Object, key As Variant
    Set dict = getPOST
    For Each key In dict.keys
        Debug.Print dict(key)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function getPOST() As Object
    Const link$ = "https://admintool.noah-connect.com/widget/attendees"
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object, oName As Object, oCom As Object
    Dim i As Long, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        For Each elem In html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
            i = i + 1
            Set oName = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
            Set oCom = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(1)
            dict(i) = oName.innerText & "-" & oCom.innerText
        Next elem
    End With
    Set getPOST = dict
End Function
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PrintResult()
    Dim items() As String, result As String, i As Long
    result = getPOST
    items = Split(result, "###")
    For i = LBound(items) To UBound(items)
        Debug.Print items(i)
    Next
End Sub
Public Function getPOST() As String
    Const link$ = "https://admintool.noah-connect.com/widget/attendees"
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object, oName As Object, oCom As Object, result As String
    result = ""
    With http
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        For Each elem In html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
            Set oName = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
            Set oCom = elem.getElementsByTagName("td")(1)
            result = result & oName.innerText & "-" & oCom.innerText & "###"
        Next elem
    End With
    getPOST = result
End Function
```